# Kendo Angular Grid: Reactive forms value is empty

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-angular-ui

I'm currently building an editable grid based on the [Kendo Angular Grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/) component.

I'm also using Reactive Forms to provide the form data to the Grid, as shown in [this example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-reactive-forms/). Actually, my code is not quite the same as in the example, as I can't use the command column (forbidden by the design team).

Right now, everything works fine, except that the `form.value` is empty...

Here is the code of my component:

```html
<!-- my-grid.component.html -->
<!-- Code voluntary simplified to improve readability -->

<kendo-grid
  #grid
  [data]="rows"
  [selectable]="{ mode: 'single', checkboxOnly: false, enabled: true }"
>
  <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
    <button (click)="editHandler()">Edit</button>
    <button (click)="saveHandler()">Save</button>
  </ng-template>

  <kendo-grid-checkbox-column [width]="48" [style]="{ 'text-align': 'center' }"></kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
  <kendo-grid-column
    *ngFor="let column of columns"
    [field]="column.field"
    [title]="column.title"
    [format]="column.getFormat()"
    [editor]="column.type"
    [hidden]="column.hidden"
    [width]="150"
  ></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

```js
// my-grid.component.ts
// Code voluntary simplified to improve readability

editHandler(): void {
  const form = {};
  this.columns
    .forEach((c) => {
      const fc = new FormControl(this.selectedRow[c.field]);
      Object.defineProperty(form, c.field, { value: fc, writable: true }); // I can't know in advance what would be the columns of my grid...
    });

  this.currentForm = new FormGroup(form); // at this moment, the FormGroup is correctly built.
  this._grid.editRow(this.selectedRowIndex, this.currentForm);
}

saveHandler(): void {
  const formValue = this.currentForm.value; // yields {} instead of { myField1: 1, myField2: 2 }...
  // ...
}
```

Here is my stack:

- angular: 9.1.11
- kendo-angular-grid: 4.7.2

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for some reason, putting the `enumerable` prop to true solves it.

```js
Object.defineProperty(form, c.field, { value: fc, writable: true, enumerable: true });
```